# FFmpeg not extracting part of the video

Tags: video-editor, ffmpeg, mencoder

I used FFmpeg to extract portion (5 seconds) of a video like this:

`ffmpeg -ss 00:30:00 -t 00:00:05 -i original.avi cut1.avi`

and also like this:

`ffmpeg -ss 1800 -t 5 -i original.avi cut1.avi`

But what FFmpeg did was create a file starting at 00:30:00 and included the rest of the file instead of just 5 seconds. So instead of having a 5 second video clip, I now have the whole file except the first 30 minutes.

What went wrong?

I tried this with `mencoder` as well -- same result.

### EDIT 1

Strangely, this worked on OS X....

### EDIT 2

After rebooting Ubuntu, I found that FFmpeg worked fine. What process was turned off that did this though?

Comment: yes, i just was just using it on mac os x and it worked great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried with this

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:30.0 -t 00:00:10.0 -i input.wmv -acodec copy -vcodec copy -async 1 output.wmv
```

for more information , look at this https://superuser.com/questions/138331/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-up-video

Comment: Yes, I have already used this from the link that you provided. It works on OS X but not on Ubuntu 11.10. I wonder if a process/daemon needs to be restarted...